# ASP.NET C# Web API sometimes return 404, sometimes work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asmx, iis-8.5

I have an issue regarding my Web API. This API calls an external API to return addresses using postcode.

So basically it works on the server it is hosted. Please take note that this is a folder converted into an application in IIS 8.5, AppPool is Integrated, Version is 4.0. On some cases it works but after 10 or 20 minutes it returns 404. It does not have a problem if I access it on the server itself only outside the network. It will work sometime but after a few minutes, 10 or 20 it wont and will return 404 then vice-versa. Does this have anything to do with Network? I'm not in-charge of it so I'm asking.

I call it using link format below:

https://example.com/ConvertedToAppFolder/FindAddress/webservice.asmx/GetAddress?postcodeval=xxxxxxx&houseno=xx

Here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Code doesn't periodically return 404s unless you have something in your code that actively DOES return a 404.

Comment: either there's a legit reason in the code to return one (e.g. you requested some resource that isn't there) or there's a network issue, but intermittent network issues would be more likely to result in other types of errors. Also, you weren't entirely clear - is it your Web API that is the source of the 404s, or the external API that it calls? When the 404s happen, have you got sufficient logging on the server to trace what code _is_ executed and trace the progress of the request? If not, you should add some logging and re-deploy.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried to monitor my calls using a custom header. It turns out it was serving an old content in the load balancer. The other server does not contain the API files so it returns 404.

Answer (score 0):

Likely it's not code problem, but API server. Try to create new pure project and access to this API, if it works fine then i wrong and it's code issue. May be it has limited access, like google translater api allow only 1,000,000 letters per day and 10,000,000 per day.